# How to show a Flutter widget as a result of action, and fade it out with no action

Tags: flutter-animation

I am trying to have some text show (or quickly fade in) as a result of user action (e.g. button click), and after a second fade out without user action. I understand that fading is accomplished by AnimatedOpacity class with opacity being set by a state variable, however it's not clear to me how to accomplish this particular scenario. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

first, text its show it self while not fade its can be considered animated too, or create some async function

check this code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FadeTextAuto extends StatefulWidget {
  const FadeTextAuto({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FadeTextAutoState createState() => _FadeTextAutoState();
}

class _FadeTextAutoState extends State<FadeTextAuto>  with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

  late Animation _animationFadeInOut;
  late AnimationController _animationController;

  bool _textShouldPlay = false;
  late Animation _animationText;
  String info = "This text appear in";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000));

    _animationFadeInOut = Tween<double>(
        begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.linear));
    _animationText = StepTween(
      begin: 1, end: 3
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.linear));
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          TextButton(onPressed: (){
            setState(() {
              info = "This text appear in";
              _textShouldPlay = false;
            });
            print(_animationText.value);
            _animationController.forward().then((value){
              if(mounted){
                setState(() {
                  _textShouldPlay = true;
                  info = "Hey read this Information";
                });
               Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),(){
                 //wait a little for text can be read
                 if(mounted){
                   setState(() {
                    _textShouldPlay = false;
                     info = "this Text will be disappear in";
                   });
                 }
               }).then((value){
                 if(mounted){
                   _animationController.reverse();
                 }
               });
              }
            });
          }, child: const Text("User Click")),
          AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _animationController,
            builder: (context, child){
              return Opacity(
                opacity: _animationFadeInOut.value,
                child: Text(
                  "$info ${_textShouldPlay?"":_animationText.value} ", style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.cyan, fontSize: 20),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

result :
[image]